# PHP add days on to a specific date?

Tags: php, datetime, date

I am feeling a bit thick today and maybe a little tired..

I am trying to add days on to a string date...

```
$startdate = "18/7/2011";

$enddate = date(strtotime($startdate) . " +1 day");
echo $startdate;
echo $enddate;
```

My heads not with it... where am i going wrong ?

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either

```
$enddate = date(strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
```

or

```
$enddate = date(strtotime($startdate . "+1 day"));
```

should work.  However, neither is working with the `18/7/2011` date.  They work fine with `7/18/2011`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IDS0gI .  Might be some localization problem.

In the first way, using the second parameter to `strtotime` says to add one day relative to that date.  In the second way, `strtotime` figures everything out.  But apparently only if the date is in the USA's date format, or in the other format using dashes: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SKJ49r

Comment: I think you might just be able to do `strtotime($startdate . "+1 day")` (as in my answer before edit and PtPazuzu's answer) but I am not sure, as I cannot test right now.  This should work, though, according to the docs.

Comment: I've tried it out:  `strtotime` seems to be messing up on 18/7 instead of 7/18.  With 7/18, both ways work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IDS0gI

Comment: Here it seems to suggest that for non-American dates, you should use dashes http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php  And dashes seem to work fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/SKJ49r

Answer (score 5):

**try this one, (tested and worked fine)**

```
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($startdate . ' +1 day'));
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($startdate . ' +2 day'));
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($startdate . ' +3 day'));
date('d-m-Y',strtotime($startdate . ' +30 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

first parameter of date() is format

d.m.Y G:i:s

for example

additionally, your $startdate is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `strtotime($startdate . "+ 1 day")` or something

Comment: I get the feeling that might work, but I don't have php handy to test.  And I can't seem to find that in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the date format
by calling changeDateFormat("18/7/2011"): returns: 2011-07-18 
if your parsing argument

> function changeDateFormat($vdate){
>                 $pos = strpos($vdate, '/');
>                 if ($pos === false) return $vdate;
>                     $pieces = explode("/", $vdate);
>                     $thisday    =   str_pad($pieces[0], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
>                     $thismonth  =   str_pad($pieces[1], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
>                     $thisyear   =   $pieces[2];
>                     $thisdate = "$thisyear-$thismonth-$thisday";
>                     return $thisdate;
>      }

And this..

> $startdate = changeDateFormat($startdate);
>   $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startdate . "+".$noOfDays." day"));

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
$startdate = "18/7/2011";
$enddate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($startdate) + strtotime("+1 day", 0));
echo $startdate;
echo $enddate;
```

First, the start date is parsed into integer, then the relative time is parsed.

You might also utilize the second parametr of strToTime:

```
$startdate = "18/7/2011";
$enddate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
```

Comment: This will add two dates together, not add 1 day.

Comment: this first one gives me 18/7/2011 and 1311961884

Comment: I would suggest YOU try it. Look at your first example a little more carefully.